# Sending code lines from the editor to the console in one click in pydev

Tags: pydev

I know I can send code to the console by using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. that is great. but how can I send code to the console while im stopping in a break point? pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> attempts to open a new console and evaluates nothing.

Is this possible? or do I need to copy paste code to the console in order to evalute local variables..?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked it and it seems that currently you have to copy/paste it when in a debug session (i.e.: in a breakpoint).

Please create a ticket at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ so that this can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use F2 to run/execute selected code in the pydev console.